# Show max variable price in shop page - Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, variant, price

I have this code to display the price.

```
function edit_selected_variation_price( $data, $product, $variation ) {
$price = $variation->price;
$price_incl_tax = $price + round($price * ( 23 / 100 ), 2);
$price_incl_tax = number_format($price_incl_tax, 2, ",", ".");
$price = number_format($price, 2, ",", ".");
$display_price = '<div><span class="price">';
$display_price .= '<span>Cena netto</span><span class="amount">' . $price .'<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> zł</small></span>';
$display_price .= '</div><div>';
$display_price .= '<span>Cena brutto</span><span class="amount">' . $price_incl_tax .'<small class="woocommerce-price-suffix"> zł</small></span>';
$display_price .= '</span></div>';
$data['price_html'] = $display_price;

return $data;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'edit_selected_variation_price', 10, 3);
```

How to get the maximum price displayed without choosing any variants?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question, you want the max price from what prices (incl tax and ...)?
However, when you have different prices in an array (or as loose variables), consider using the PHP `max()` function:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

That will return the highest value (Hope that's what you're after)

Comment: What I have now is ok, but the prices show only after selecting the variants. I want the highest prices displayed by default.